# Returning exactly what string was found in an array

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do is check an array against some HTML code to see if of those values exist, I can do that fine with LINQ:

```
keys.Any(pageHtml.Contains)
```

What I can't seem to do is find the way to return what exactly was found? The code above just returns `bool` - if it's found, is there a away I can return what string(s) was actually found?

I have tried searching but most threads are just ways to see if the values are found and not actually retrieving them.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var result = keys.FirstOrDefault(key => pageHtml.Contains(key));` to find either the first occurence of such a key or `null` (`default`) if nothing meets the condition

Comment: Or to get all matches `keys.Where(x => pageHtml.Contains(x))`

Comment: Thank you guys ```FirstOrDefault``` and ```Where``` are new ones on me :) thank you.